# iOS AutoFill password doesn't work in production app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, passwords, autofill

I creating app in Xamarin.iOS, and Password Autofill feature works in DEBUG (development) mode, but doesn't work in Release (production) from TestFlight and AppStore. 
Distribution Profile has Enabled AutoFill Credential Provider and Associated Domains services.

The Associated Domains File and Entitlements have next contents:

**apple-app-site-association**:

```
{      
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "TEAM_IDENTIFIER.APP_BUNDLE_ID",
        "paths": [
          "*",
          "/"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [ "TEAM_IDENTIFIER.APP_BUNDLE_ID" ]
  }
}
```

**Entitlements.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
      <string>applinks:my_associated_domain.com</string>
      <string>webcredentials:my_associated_domain.com</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

What could be the reason that autofill doesn't work in the production app?

Comment: What is the mean of "doesn't work".Did the passsword show on the keyboard?

Comment: The password did not show above the keyboard.
There is not appear the dialog box to save the password.

Comment: Did you ever find a reason for this not working?

Comment: @Daniel No, аnd Apple Support ignores no response.